# Disable panning on some elements Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js with react, and I have some tools implemented on it.
Here is how it looks:

[image]

However there is a panning tool, for which I am using the `relativePan()` function from fabric. One problem I am having is that the rulers (marked with red) should not be moving when dragging with the pan tool. 
They are also part of the canvas as every other element.

Is there any way to disable panning for some elements? I have tried:

```
lockMovementX
lockMovementY
selectable: false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to subtract the moving coordinates from the stationary object(s) when panning:

```
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
  if (panning && e && e.e) {
    moveX = e.e.movementX;
    moveY = e.e.movementY;
    topRuler.set({
      top: topRuler.top - moveY,
      left: topRuler.left - moveX
    });
    leftRuler.set({
      top: leftRuler.top - moveY,
      left: leftRuler.left - moveX
    });
    canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(moveX, moveY));
  }
});
```

Here's a working JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/z3p8utmc/.

Comment: No worries.  Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Hello Tim, One more problem. It is working perfectly, however I have a combination with Zoom, and when the canvas is zoomed in or zoomed out, the rulers are still moving: http://prntscr.com/edxd1a

Comment: How does your zoom function look now?  Can you share some code?

Comment: In fact this is what I am trying to achieve: https://vid.me/qs5Q  So the rulers need to be somehow positioned depending on the canvas size and the zoom level when Panning, without moving together with the other elements.  Thank you so much for the help! Really appreciated.

Comment: Dear TIm, did you have a chance to look at the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind opening it as a separate question with what you've tried and a JSFiddle (perhaps the one you updated above)?  Thank you.

Comment: Sure! Done here ->                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42578824/fabric-js-position-elements-relative-to-getzoom-and-getwidth-getheight

Comment: Would you be please able to help me or give me at least a direction how to do it, because i really need this. Thanks, Goran

Comment: @GoranGjorgievski I just provided an answer.  The trick is calculating and recalculating everything as user actions are taken and events are firing.  I hope it helps!