# Fabric.js position elements relative to getZoom() and getWidth()/getHeight()

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I am using Fabric.js with React/Redux and i am trying to achieve the following effect on canvas: (note i have 2 rulers on the top and left which shouldn't move around when panning, just horizontally and vertically).

This is a video of the effect I am trying to get: https://vid.me/qs5Q

I have the following code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var topRuler = new fabric.Text('this is the top ruler', {
  top: 0,
  left: 60,
  selectable: false
});
var leftRuler = new fabric.Text('this is the left ruler', {
  top: 150,
  left: -125,
  selectable: false
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  radius: 20,
  fill: 'green',
  left: 180,
  top: 100
});
var triangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  fill: 'green',
  left: 150,
  top: 170
});
var panning = false;
var panningOn = false;
leftRuler.setAngle(-90).setCoords();
canvas.add(circle, triangle, topRuler, leftRuler);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
 if (panningOn) panning = false;
});

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(e) {
 if (panningOn) panning = true;
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(e) {
  if (panning && e && e.e) {
  moveX = e.e.movementX;
  moveY = e.e.movementY;
  topRuler.set({
    top: topRuler.top - moveY,
    left: topRuler.left - moveX
  });

  leftRuler.set({
    top: leftRuler.top - moveY,
    left: leftRuler.left - moveX
  });
   canvas.relativePan(new fabric.Point(moveX, moveY));
  }
});
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  panningOn = !panningOn;
  canvas.selection = !panningOn;
  canvas.defaultCursor = 'default';
  $('#toggle').html('Turn Panning ON');
  if (panningOn) {
   $('#toggle').html('Turn Panning OFF');
   canvas.defaultCursor = 'move';
  }
});

 /* ZOOM FUNCTIONS */
 $('#zoomIn').click(function(){
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() * 1.1 ) ;
 });

 $('#zoomOut').click(function(){
    canvas.setZoom(canvas.getZoom() / 1.1 ) ;
 });
```

This is a working JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z3p8utmc/19/
The code is not complete since I do not know exactly how to position the rulers, tried to play with viewPort, canvas size, etc. but did not manage to get the same effect.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a screen shot of the results:

[image: FabricJS - Rulers: Zooming & Panning, based on Video]

Here's the two zoom functions:

```
/* ZOOM FUNCTIONS */
$('#zoomIn').click(function() {
  rectangle.set({
    width: rectangle.width * 1.1,
    height: rectangle.height * 1.1
  });
  rectangle.setCoords();
  textSample.set({
    top: 60 + (textSample.top - 60) * 1.1,
    left: 60 + (textSample.left - 60) * 1.1,
    scaleX: textSample.scaleX * 1.1,
    scaleY: textSample.scaleY * 1.1
  });
  textSample.setCoords();
  setPins();
  addLeftRuler();
  addTopRuler();
  resizeCanvas();
});
$('#zoomOut').click(function() {
  rectangle.set({
    width: rectangle.width / 1.1,
    height: rectangle.height / 1.1
  });
  rectangle.setCoords();
  textSample.set({
    top: 60 + (textSample.top - 60) / 1.1,
    left: 60 + (textSample.left - 60) / 1.1,
    scaleX: textSample.scaleX / 1.1,
    scaleY: textSample.scaleY / 1.1
  })
  textSample.setCoords();
  setPins();
  addLeftRuler();
  addTopRuler();
  resizeCanvas();
});
```

Panning is done using a 3rd-Party control, and the traditional way, since that's what the video shows (and you wanted) - top and left rulers are kept in place by updating their positions as scrolling occurs.

Zooming is done by scaling the individual objects based on point (60, 60) - as in the video. Pins are reset, rulers are rescaled, and canvas is resized - as needed.

The trick is calculating and recalculating everything as user actions are taken and events are firing.

Hopefully this gets you the canvas foundation you need to build upon.

Here's a working JSFiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/rekrah/hs6jL8d4/.

Comment: Dear @Tim would you mind taking a look at this please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42781527/fabric-js-draw-regular-octagon ?